# Looped square (Bowen knot) symbol?

Tags: symbols

Is there a symbol in LaTeX for ⌘?

More info about it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_key

Comment: According to [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) it does not exist. But detexify is not complete.